# Wacom web browser plugin?

Tags: javascript, browser-plugin, wacom, pen-tablet

I found [this web page which describes in detail a browser plugin that exposes Wacom tablet features such as pressure sensitivity in JavaScript](http://www.wacomeng.com/web/).  Unfortunately, the download link is dead.  Does this product exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressure sensitivity is now exposed by the browser's Pointer Events API for all supported tablets (not just Wacom). Pointer events such as onpointermove will contain a ["pressure" field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent/pressure) that ranges between 0.0 and 1.0.

Pointer Events are supported by Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer (10+), Microsoft Edge and Safari (13+) on macOS and Windows 8+ (Windows 7 doesn't provide pressure information). See:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer

Answer (score 3):

Also, someone has written a Linux plugin using NPAPI: https://github.com/ZaneA/WacomWebPlugin

Answer (score 2):

plugin file is included in Driver Installer.

If you extract Wacom Pentablet driver installer for Windows (this is executable zip archive), 
you can find TabletPlugins\fbWTPInstall_x86.exe (and  fbWTPInstall_x64.exe).

This file is "Wacom Tablet Plugin installer for Netscape Browsers".
So, execute it, then available Web browser plugin demos.

Comment: Where do I find this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the plugin uses NPAPI, and browsers are progressively dropping support for that ([Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation), [Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/)), so it seems like the driver is no longer useful right now.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the new site here:

http://us.wacom.com/developerrelations

It's true that the plugin itself is contained in the driver.

Comment: What do I do at this link?

Comment: Click on 'Web', wasn't that what you were looking for? Perhaps you can explain what it is you seek, and for what purpose?